# Spring Boot static content url mapping

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-web

Is anybody here who know how to create a mapping file from static directory to respond for certain url in Spring Boot?

For example, I have file in directory /resource in Spring Boot structure

```
resources/static/html/index.html
```

and I want it to respond to url

```
/index
```

No catalogue path, no .html postfix

Answer (score 1):

File `index.html` is served as default HTML file from certain directory. So if you want to serve it from `http://domain:port/index` URL, you should place it into `resources/static/index/index.html`.

Answer (score 0):

As I research more, url mapping is possible only if You use template engine like Thymeleaf and then application will became context aware.

Answer (score -1):

Use Thymeleaf and then add your .html files to resources/templates/ and they will be discovered automatically.